# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Undefined symbol: _RCTPresentedViewController, Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule

Tags: react-native, braintree, react-native-braintree-dropin-ui

I have an issue when trying to integrate this library.

I have already tried the following solutions.
https://github.com/braintree/braintree-ios-drop-in/issues/209#issuecomment-979296320

I also enable Rosetta from getInfo and then open XCode but this solution still received the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
Showing Recent Errors Only
Undefined symbol: _RCTPresentedViewController
Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule
```

[image: MicrosoftTeams-image]

**Step to reproduce**

1. Install react-native-braintree-dropin-ui npm.
2. Install pod
3. After installing the pod and running the app and get the same error again.

**System Configuration**
MacBook Pro M1 Silicon Chip
Simulator 14 Pro

react-native:0.68.2
iOS version 16.1
Android 33

Used following Braintree npm versions

```
'Braintree', '~> 5.10'
'BraintreeDropIn', '~> 9.6'
'Braintree/DataCollector', '~> 5.10'
'Braintree/ApplePay', '~> 5.9'
'Braintree/Venmo', '~> 5.9'
```